# Android background jobs for synchronization with a web service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

Could you pease tell me what is the correct way to do the synchronization jobs in Android (e.g. if I have about 5 jobs)? 

**Note!** By synchronization job I mean a thread which runs in background and sends some data (e.g. analytics) via a Web Service...

For more details please read a more detailed description:

I've got a task to implement some background jobs which will synchronize some data with a restful web service. Some of the jobs should be scheduled periodically with a specific delay. If there is no internet connection then I simply cache the data and later when the connection reappears I try to run the jobs.
Taking into consideration that creating new threads is quite expensive and especially on mobile development, I'm using a cached thread pool (ExecutorService) and every time some actions are requested for processing I'm trying to reuse the threads. I don't use AsyncTask because I've replaced this with this Executor Service (Executors.newCachedTreadPool) and its convenient for me because I don't need to create many AsyncTasks as I reuse the threads from ES... In order to support the scheduled jobs, I use another thread pool(ScheduledExecutorService) and use Callable because I need to see the execution result. I've got a complex logic here... So, when a particular action is done in the app, the 1st thread pool (is like the AsyncTask) will work like an AsyncTask, the advantage is that I don't create new threads but I reus them. This will not block the UI's main thread. It will delegate to the scheduled executor which will do its job.
This solution works. And it sounds good for me as I'm coming from server side, but I'm interested to know how this must be done correctly on Android? Is this too sophisticated for a mobile app? 
Merci,
Serge

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a sync adapter. See http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html. A sync adapter runs in the background, it's managed by the system, and scheduled efficiently so that your sync doesn't waste battery power. Best of all, the system will automatically detect network connectivity and queue up your sync adapter if necessary. If you want, you can use multiple sync adapters.

Notice that although it *seems* that sync adapters need a content provider and an authenticator, they really don't.

Comment: Thank you Joe, your answer is really helpful. I've read the article and I'm going to use the Sync Adapters. It seems this is what I was looking for... Many thanks.